# JAVAFx and Clean Architecture

Tags: javafx, clean-architecture

I'm making an app that try to follow the Clean architecture guideline. The app use JavaFX as UI. JavaFX is make to use the MVC architecture. Is there a way to use both in conjunction like this?

[image]

My problem is i can't find a way to have a Controller and a Presenter that interact with the FXML file.

Currently i have this :

1. An FXML file that declare a controller with fx:controller attribute
2. A controller That handle event and called a usecase
3. A usecase like this:

   ```
   public class SomeUseCase implements UseCase<Observable<String>> {

       private SomeRepository repository;

       public SomeUseCase(SomeRepository repository) {
           repository = repository;
       }

       @Override
       public void execute(Request request, Presenter presenter) {
           SomeUseCaseRequest req = (SomeUseCaseRequest) request;

           // I skip mapper that translate from request to entity and entity to repository
           // And vice-versa for the respponse for clarity

           presenter.render(this.repository.fetch(req.someParam));
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Not sure how closely this follows your diagram, but have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx.

Comment: @Scandinave have you found a suitable solution?